# JavaScript Fetching Multiple Requests In An Order

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to fetch multiple requests in an order in React. There are 3 requests,

- first one gathering encoded information from backend
- get token from authentication server
- use api with the token.

All of them must be in order. But I am having difficulties because of async fetch function. I can't reach fetch's response outside of .then() block.

To solve it, I used await / async. But it caused another problem. My 3 requests must be in a sequencial order. When I use async, order gets broken.

Here is the code.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { code: '', encoded: '', access_token: '', refresh_token: '' };
  }

  getCarDetails() {

    const carId = '2F3A228F6F66AEA580'
    var query = 'https://api.mercedes-benz.com/experimental/connectedvehicle/v1/vehicles/'.concat(carId).concat('/doors')

    fetch(query, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '.concat(this.state.access_token),
        'accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  getToken() {

    var post_data = {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: this.state.code,
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost'
    }

    fetch('https://api.secure.mercedes-benz.com/oidc10/auth/oauth/v2/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Basic '.concat(this.state.encoded),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }),
      body: queryString.stringify(post_data)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ access_token: data.access_token, refresh_token: data.refresh_token }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  getEncodedClientIdAndClientSecret() {
    if (this.state.code != null) {

      fetch('http://localhost:8000/encodeClientIdAndSecret', {
        method: 'POST'
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ encoded: data.encoded }))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const values = queryString.parse(this.props.location.search)
    this.setState({ code: values.code })

    console.log(this.state)
    this.getEncodedClientIdAndClientSecret();
    console.log(this.state) //this state is empty
    //this.getToken();
    //this.getCarDetails();

  }
```

## AWAIT / ASYNC

```
  async getEncodedClientIdAndClientSecret() {
    if (this.state.code != null) {

      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/encodeClientIdAndSecret', {
        method: 'POST'
      })


      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data)
    }
  }
```

If I put await / async, I am having sequence problem between 3 requests.

Comment: "I used await / async" - show corresponding code. I ask it 'cuz i got confused by phrase "When I use async, order gets broken.". Async/await has no problems with order, it should not get broken

Comment: try [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: I added await / async example @lucifer63

Comment: First thought is you could use `async componentDidMount()` then `await` each of your function calls inside that. That may not be the best solution, however.

Comment: Thanks! Now look: make all your get* functions async, then call them with await. This way the order is preserved

Answer (score 0):

in order to use async await on methods like

```
await getEncodedClientIdAndClientSecret();
await getToken();
```

you need to first return a promise from those functions like:

```
getToken() {
    var post_data = {
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code: this.state.code,
      redirect_uri: 'http://localhost'
    }

    return fetch('https://api.secure.mercedes-benz.com/oidc10/auth/oauth/v2/token', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Authorization': 'Basic '.concat(this.state.encoded),
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }),
      body: queryString.stringify(post_data)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ access_token: data.access_token, refresh_token: data.refresh_token }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

so it can wait for the promise to finish, othewise they will run in parallel and finish in random order.